# Mailspring ridicoulus high memory usage

Tags: ram, memory-usage

Mailspring is advertised as a lightweight client but it is consuming 1G+ of RAM, which compared to thunderbird is a lot, is there any way to fix this?
[image]

Comment: I can't answer your question but I too have noticed mailspring using lots of memory. I use the snap version (1.9.2) on Ubuntu 21.04 and when started the mailspring processes use about 200MB but that slowly grows and grows and grows over several days until it's using gigabytes. Seems to be reported here but no resolution: https://community.getmailspring.com/t/high-ram-usage-multiple-gb/2837

Comment: https://community.getmailspring.com/t/mailspring-has-high-cpu-usage/87/16 suggests to check and remove hidden files on the root of mailspring But you are better off filing a bugreport; we will likely not have a fix for this.